# How to add new field in registration form in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am using shopify and i find that how we can add extra field in registration form but not done.

I checked here it only add in registration form but when i get value it does not retrieve.

[Click Here](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/customization/forms/get-more-information-with-customer-registration-form)

Comment: What is the name field of your extra field?

Comment: suppose we add 'dealer' input field.

Comment: Your name field should be `name="customer[note][Dealear]"` in that case.

Comment: Yes i did like this and when i submit the form it was successfully submitted without error but after login when i tried to get info of this field it shown empty.

Comment: Customer notes can't be accessed from the liquid. They are only for merchant reference, you can't output them in any way (except the Shopify API).

Comment: so if we talk about customer notes where we can get this in admin?
I want to add only a simple text field in which i can pass value on register form and get when i logged is it possible?

Comment: Please refer to https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/display-customer-notes-on-the-frontend-224380 and https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/how-to-access-to-the-customer-note-with-liquid-186535 so that I don't repeat myself.

Comment: ok.But here i want to add only a simple field not like customer note.I want to add like first_name how can it be possible?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, Shopify does not provide the ability to add extra fields to the registration form that can be viewed after the form is submitted. While they do provide the ability to append information to the customer note through the `name="customer[note][key]"` convention, this customer note cannot be retrieved through liquid after the registration form as been submitted.

To get around this limitation, you'll need to leverage a pre-existing Shopify application or write your own application to make server-side calls to the Shopify API. In the past, we've written little functions using `serverless.io` to save and retrieve metafields attached to the customer object.

Alternatively, the Shopify app Accentuate (https://accentuate.io/#customer-fields) supposedly has created a workflow to save customer metafields directly from the front-end of a Shopify theme.